# Culture Datetime variations

Tags: c#, vsto

I have a VSTO App that performs a mail merge and other operations.

The mail merge db is an Excel db, with has some `DateTime` fields which are stored as (dd/MM/YYYY) (e.g. 29/04/2012). My problem is that in Excel the Dates look good, but in Word it shows in other format (MM/dd/yyyy) (e.g. 4/29/2012). When try to get this date on my VSTO App, it throws an error of conversion indicating that the string has the wrong format.

All this happens on the same machine. If I change my cultural information in VSTO to en-US, it works fine.

```
// This way fails 
edictoActual.FechaEdicto = Convert.ToDateTime(fields(fieldFechaEdicto).value); 

// This way Works
IFormatProvider Formato = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
edictoActual.FechaEdicto = Convert.ToDateTime(fields(fieldFechaEdicto).value,Formato);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: can you `format` the date to the expected output that you are wanting Juan..?

Comment: No, the date came to me as a String ´fields(fieldFechaEdicto).value´ it is stored in the mailmerge  datasource

Comment: Juan I will post an example that you can use to determine how to do this using a simple switch statement.. based on this example you should be able to see what I am trying and you can add to the example as you wish..

Comment: you can focus on `Case 10:`  in the code this is something that I have written and used multiple times because some data never comes in the 10 digit date format all the time when working with passed in data.. hope the example give you an idea.. also in the code you can write your own method that parses / build a substring to pass back the correct date format.. the options are endless..

Comment: How do you know if `"02/03/2012"` means 2nd of March, or February 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string DateString = "29/04/2012"; //DateString needs to be replaced with your fields value as a string
var dateLength = DateString.Length;
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime dateVal;
switch (dateLength)
{
     case 8:
        {
          dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "M/d/yyyy", culture);
            break;
        }
    case 9:
        {
            // he you can add your own additional if(){} condition to check if date value Day has a length of 2 
            // if so then you know that the date is in m/dd/yyyy format
            // otherwise you know it's in mm/d/yyyy but 
            dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "M/dd/yyyy", culture);
            break;
        }
    case 10:
        {
            dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", culture);
            //or change the above to look like the following 
            //dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", culture);
            break;
        }

}
```

Comment: Very tks for your help, it seems definitelly must use culture. Tks a Lot

Comment: Do Word and Excel have different default cultures that take over if none are provided?

Comment: Tks Ryan. really don´t understand the comment

Comment: The code above is not very useful since the format `"M/d/yyyy"` will work even if the month number and/or the date number has two digits. Also, why use the "English (United States)" culture? Is the application targeted anglophone people in the U.S.A.? I would suggest `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` which has the following characteristics: (1) Uses the `GregorianCalendar`. (2) Use the string `"/"` (slash) as the `DateSeparator`.

Comment: Jeepe the code was not intended in the `m/d/yyyy` to be part of his issue however the code will work if you look at who date is being formatted based on the `Case` statement.. you will see that it will work.. not everyone gets `Dates` in the traditional `mm/dd/yyyy` format that we see in `US Culture` I've posted the answer to give the OP an additional option / way of being able to fix his code based on the date format.. think outside the box..

Comment: Tks Jeepe, My problem is that i Have no control over de data source, simple it comes to me "as is". It means if they came to me as "4/29/2012" String I' must interpretate it. My final option was use a Cultureinfo  config parm that allow to me or my user to configure the way DateTime's must be interpretated.